# copy entire directory excluding a file

Tags: linux, cp

As we know, *cp -r source_dir intended_new_directory* creates a copy of source directory with a new name. Now I want to do the same but want to exclude a particular file. I have found some related answers here, using *tar* and *rsync*, but in those solutions I need to create the destination directory first (using mkdir).
I honestly searched a lot, but didn't find exactly what I want.
So far the best I got is this:

```
tar -c --exclude=\*.dll --exclude=\*.exe sourceDir | tar -x -C destDir
```

(from http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/how-to-copy-an-entire-directory-structure-except-certain-files-385321/)

Answer (score 2):

If you have binutils, you could use [find](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html) to filter next [cpio](https://www.gnu.org/software/cpio/manual/cpio.html) to copy (and create directories) :

```
find <sourceDir>  \( ! -name *.dll \) -a \( ! -name *.exe \) | cpio -dumpv <destDir>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this by excluding the file using 'grep -v' ->

```
cp `ls | grep -v <exclude-file>` <dest-dir>
```

Comment: This will not copy the subdirs.. you need to modify the command accordingly.

Comment: sorry, don't understand the command. Where do I put the source directory?

Comment: Here @dganesh2002 copies all the files from the _current_ directory to the destination directory. OK if there are no subdirectories, filenames don't have spaces, and number of files in the current directory is not too large.

Comment: thanks much to dganesh2002 and @atycnth. Though I still need to create the dest_dir myself, I like this solution because its mechanism is simple, and I can easily remember it.

Answer (score 0):

If the directory is not very large I used to write something like this:

```
src=path/to/source/directory
dst=path/to/destination/directory
find $src -type f | while read f ; do mkdir -p "$dst/`dirname $f`"; cp "$f" "$dst/$f" ; done
```

Here we list all regular files in `$src`, iterate over this list and for each file make a directory in `$dst` if it does not exist yet (`-p` option of `mkdir`), then copy the file to that directory.

The above command will copy all the files.  Finally, just use

```
find $src -type f | grep -v whatever | while ...... # same as above
```

to filter out the files you don't need (e.g. `\.bak$`, `\.orig$`, or whatever files you don't want to copy).

Answer (score -1):

Move all exclude file into home or other directory,copy the directory containing all remaining files to the destination folder then restore all exclude files.

```
#cd mydirectory
#mv exclude1 exclude2 /home/
#cp mydirectory destination_folder/
#cd /home/
#mv eclude1 exclude2 mydirectory/
```